# wget interrupted by a certificate problem

Tags: wget, certificates

I wanted to download a file using `wget https://curl.haxx.se/download/archeology/curl-7.16.2.tar.gz`. Done that from a friend's PC and got no errors.

However, when trying to do so from my PC, on which I played a bit with certificates, while establishing an FTPS client, I got this error:

```
ERROR: cannot verify curl.haxx.se's certificate, issued by '=== MY CERTIFICATE DETAILS ===':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to curl.haxx.se insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

I used the `--no-check-certificate` to overcome this and it went fine, but my question is, why did this error pop up? I didn't ask for a secure connection, simply `wget` - which does no secure checks, from what I saw on my friend's PC.

How can I prevent this error in future downloads? (solving the underline cause, not using the `--no-check-certificate`)

**EDIT:**

```
$ apt-cache policy wget
wget:
  Installed: 1.15-1ubuntu1.14.04.1
  Candidate: 1.15-1ubuntu1.14.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 1.15-1ubuntu1.14.04.1 0
        500 http://172.18.177.211/14.04.3/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://172.18.177.211/14.04.3/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.15-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://172.18.177.211/14.04.3/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
```

---

```
$ apt-cache policy libssl1.0.0 ca-certificates
libssl1.0.0:
  Installed: 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.15
  Candidate: 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.15
  Version table:
 *** 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.15 0
        500 http://172.18.177.211/14.04.3/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://172.18.177.211/14.04.3/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.0.1f-1ubuntu2 0
        500 http://172.18.177.211/14.04.3/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
ca-certificates:
  Installed: 20141019ubuntu0.14.04.1
  Candidate: 20141019ubuntu0.14.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 20141019ubuntu0.14.04.1 0
        500 http://172.18.177.211/14.04.3/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://172.18.177.211/14.04.3/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     20130906ubuntu2 0
        500 http://172.18.177.211/14.04.3/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
```

Comment: It seems that you have outdated certificates in your system. Please add output of `apt-cache policy wget libgnutls??` to the question. I just tested your link on my fully updated system and I do not have any warnings or errors related to TLS/SSL certificate. So the problem is on your (client) side. If you have problems with other HTTPS-resources, it may be proxy-problem.

Comment: Trying... but I get: `Unable to locate package libgnutls`

Comment: @ CIsForCookies  And what about `apt-cache policy wget`?

Comment: Also `apt-cache policy libssl1.0.0 ca-certificates` will be useful.

Comment: So you have outdated [`ca-certificates` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty-updates/ca-certificates) (compare yours *20141019ubuntu0.14.04.1* with *20170717~14.04.1*). The main problem is that your local mirror is out of sync.

Answer (score 1):

You can preconfigure your wget calls in `/etc/wgetrc` or for a specific user in `~/.wgetrc`. Perhaps on your friend's PC one of these files contained the directive

`check_certificate = on/off`

Further options see https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Startup-File