# wget fails by a certificate problem

Tags: networking, wget, openssl, certificates

Same problem as [wget interrupted by a certificate problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041876/wget-interrupted-by-a-certificate-problem/):

After `do-release-upgrade` from 16.04 to 18.01

```
Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts. 
Check your Internet connection or proxy settings
```

`wget https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts`

```
--2018-09-15 08:03:41--  https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts
Resolving changelogs.ubuntu.com (changelogs.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.95.15, 2001:67c:1560:8008::11
Connecting to changelogs.ubuntu.com (changelogs.ubuntu.com)|91.189.95.15|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify changelogs.ubuntu.com's certificate, issued by ‘CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US’:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to changelogs.ubuntu.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

Also (as root):

```
# update-ca-certificates

Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
```

---

```
# wget https://www.google.com/

--2018-09-16 16:54:31--  https://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... 216.58.201.164, 2a00:1450:4003:80a::2004
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|216.58.201.164|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify www.google.com's certificate, issued by ‘CN=Google Internet Authority G3,O=Google Trust Services,C=US’:
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to www.google.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

Update 2018-10-23:

```
openssl s_client -connect www.google.com:443 -debug
```

fails

```
openssl s_client  -connect www.google.com:443 --debug --CApath /etc/ssl/certs/
```

works

```
 wget https://www.google.com/  --ca-directory=/etc/ssl/certs/
```

works, so why is the default ca-directory not `/etc/ssl/certs/`? and do I set it?

New Update and solved:

```
strace -e openat wget https://your-url
```

I saw that it was using `/usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.1`, so I found one openssl installed on `/usr/local`, and after deleting it, the problem was fixed.

Thanks

Comment: Any special configuration involved in `/etc/wgetrc` or `${HOME}/.wgetrc`? Also try to reinstall `wget` with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall wget`.

Comment: No , ${HOME}/.wgetrc does not exit and /etc/wgetrc is unchanged , reinstall wget didn't solve the issue

Comment: Are there actually any certificates in `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` ?

Comment: ll  -h /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 203K set 17 02:46 /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

Comment: `openssl version -a` is a good command for situations like this, you can see if OPENSSLDIR is set incorrectly (which is probably was for your dud copy in /usr/local/lib)

Answer (score 4):

The thread: [Problem with certificates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/420860/problem-with-certificates) helped me to solve the problem.

user [mirabilos](https://askubuntu.com/users/222799/mirabilos) explain the commands to reinstall the ca-certificates

> ```
> sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
> sudo apt-get -f install
> sudo dpkg --purge --force-depends ca-certificates
> sudo apt-get -f install
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You once compiled and installed openssl yourself and it still exists or maybe you removed that installation:

If the foldef `/usr/local/ssl/` exists, check that the file `/usr/local/ssl/cert.pem` exists, if not run:

```
sudo ln -s  /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /usr/local/ssl/cert.pem
```

Comment: I saw that it was using /usr/local/lib/libssl.so.1.1, so I found one openssl installed on /usr/local, and after deleting it, the problem was fixed.

Comment: Normally, I never type 'thank you' comments. But I've been searching for 5 days for the solution on how a manual installed `openssl` which was then removed and restored back to an 'apt'-installed `openssl` can be used. I kept getting certificate invalid errors. This helped me a lot: Thank you!

Comment: Thank you -- I've spent the whole day trying to resolve the issue caused by the missing `/usr/local/ssl/cert.pem`

Answer (score 1):

I have installed it. It worked for Ubuntu 16.4 LTS

```
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates
```

Answer (score -1):

i faced same kind of issue. after the multiple checks i did below actions then fixed the certificate error for https wget connections.

Number of required root ca certificate is missing in the certificate path

```
root@SINGPWEBSERVER:~# cd /usr/lib/ssl/certs
root@SINGPWEBSERVER:/usr/lib/ssl/certs# ls -l | wc -l
12
```

Installed all the certificate using below command (select all the certificates)

```
 root@SINGPWEBSERVER:/usr/lib/ssl/certs# sudo dpkg-reconfigure ca-certificates
```

After the above extract command all the required HTTPS connection CA certificates installed

```
root@SINGPWEBSERVER:/usr/lib/ssl/certs# ls -l | wc -l
270
```

Find the https connection success result for your reference

```
root@SINGPWEBSERVER:/tmp# wget https://www.google.com/
--2021-07-28 15:23:19--  https://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... 142.250.204.68, 2404:6800:4005:813::2004
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|142.250.204.68|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html.6’
index.html.6                                   [ <=>                                                                                     ]  15.45K  --.-KB/s    in 0.001s
2021-07-28 15:23:19 (21.9 MB/s) - ‘index.html.6’ saved [15821]
```